# windows phone 8.1 emulator in windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have finally added the universal tools to visual studio 2015 Community,and I have created a windows phone project,after that,I tried to install windows phone 8.1 emulators but I get this message:

[image]

my system is:

```
Windows 8.1 Professionnel 
Processeur: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU P6200 @2.13Ghz 2.13Ghz
RAM:4.00Go
System Type: 64 bits,x64 processor
```

I know that my PC dosn't accept virtualisation,is there please any windows phone emulator I can dowload to test my windows phone application

thanks a lot for help

Comment: check headnail's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459692/windows-phone-8-emulator-on-non-slat-machines

Comment: thanks bazsibazsi for the link

Answer (score 1):

if your CPU doesn't support VT-x you are out of luck. [Hyper-V requires VT-x and SLAT support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/07/bringing-hyper-v-to-windows-8.aspx) support to run. Your extremely old CPU doesn't support both requirements.

Buy a newer laptop/2-1 device with a CPU that supports Hyper-V.

Comment: thanks magicandre1981 for your reply even when I try to use vmware workstation I get problem that my host does not support Intel VT-x :(

Comment: in this case you have to buy a newer developer machine which supports VT-x and SLAT.